# How to create a crystal report just like this?

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

I have this request from a client, they want their report to be in a format like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkwqi.jpg)

This is a winform recipe batching application.

Basically I have an ingredient table, and formula-ingredient table.

When this formula is "used" , it's save to a finished-formula table that has the ingredient and actual amounts used.

I have already done a report and its working. But, the customer wants the format just like in the imaged i linked.

Is this possible with crystal reports?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be possible with a Crosstab in Crystal Reports, but its hard to say for certain without knowing the structure of your dataset.

Comment: Cross tab did the trick. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction